# How can I show the toast from the service in the specific activity

Tags: android, toast

I have activity A, from this activity I start activity B, which have a button "ok". When the button is clicked  some event happens, this event is processed by the service and the service shows toast in activity B, after that B finished.

The problem is that the Activiti B stops running too fast, and user can't see the toast long enough.

How can I wait while activity A come to the front and shows toast there(in the A)?

Comment: are u making toast in onCreate? if yes it will be better to make toast onResume method that time screen comes in fornt

Comment: Can't you show the toast directly from service? The toast message is relevant from what activity is currently shown?

Comment: Increase the timeout of toast, the third parameter of makeText is duration.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this hack..

create a handler in activity B. Show you Toast before hadler & code for returning back to Activity A inside handler run() method.

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
 handler.postDelayed(
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Place your code here for returning back to activity A
            }
        }, 1000);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- Start Activity B as **startActivityForResult** from Activity A and
- then **onActivityResult** check if the result you are getting from
  Activity B is OK
- then show up a toast on Activity A.

Tutorial link showing how to use startActivityForResult are given below :

https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=startactivity+for+result+tutorial+android&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=pNU2UtvSD8uGrgfPxYGACg

Answer (score 0):

Try This if It works...

```
 1. Create a Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable(){
public void run()
{
//first Activity
}
});t1.start();
 2. join t1

    try

     {

       t1.join();

     }

 3. Similarly,create other thread with Second Activity

 4. This will make second thread to execute only after First .Giving u the time to view the Toast message

`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to finish activity B after the the toast dismiss.You can user-defined the toast during seconds.But android doesn't provide any APIs to do this.

We can use reflect to solve this problem.

Suppose you want to finish activity B after the toast showing 10 seconds.

> Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "ToastMessage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
>
> try {
>
> //get "mTN" field from toast
>
> Field field = toast.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTN");
>
> field.setAccessible(true);
>
> Object obj = field.get(toast);
>
> //get method "show"
>
> Method method = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("show", null);
>
> //show the toast
>
> method.invoke(obj, null);
>
> } catch (Exception e) {}
>
> //dismiss the toast after 10 seconds
>
> new Thread(){
>
> public void run() {
>
> try {
>
> sleep(10000);
>
> } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>
> e.printStackTrace();
>
> }
>
> try{
>
> Method method =  obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("hide", null);
>
> method.invoke(obj,null);
>
> //finish Activity B here
>
> finish();
>
> }
>   catch (Exception e){}
>
> };
>
> }.start();